# What is the best way to handle a prop that pretty much gets passed everywhere?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object that gets passed as a prop to probably 70% of my components. What is the best way to handle that?

I am currently doing prop drilling and just passing it everywhere.
I am considering using React's Context system as an alternative.

Are there better ways or are my approaches sufficient?

Comment: If it changes, then use context, like you're considering. If it never changes, export a const from a file and import it where its needed.

Comment: [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: It is an object that gets initialized in the App() function in App.js and then passed down as a prop.

Comment: State management ( https://recoiljs.org/ or https://redux.js.org/ ) or Prop drilling (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)